# DNS Forward based on multiple conditions (Linux Bind)

Tags: linux, dns, centos, bind9

I'm trying to deploy A dns Forwarder using Bind9 (Linux).
I want that my server will be able to analyze requests and forward it to exeternal DNS (internet) or internal using condition implemented.
So we will use :
DNS forwarder : server that will analyze and forwarder requests to internal or external DNS
Internal DNS : Server that resolve only internal names (domain.company)
DNS : 8.8.8.8 :resolving external address

So the goal is when i try to resolve a domain name/URI. If it's internal that request should be forwarded to internal DNS else it should be forwarded to 8.8.8.8

```
Exemple1 : nslookup google.com should be forwarded to 8.8.8.8

Exemple2 : nslookup application.domain.company should be forwarded to internal dnsserver
```

and here the content of /etc/named.conf

```
//
// named.conf


options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        listen-on-v6  { any; };
        auth-nxdomain no;
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursion yes;
        allow-query     { 127.0.0.1; IPCLIENT2; IPclient1; };
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                        };
        forward first;


        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "domain.compagny" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { IP_internaldns; };
};
    zone "domain2.compagny" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { IP_internaldns; };
};

#include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
#include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Here if I execute : `nslookup google.com or yahoo` It resolves correctly
But if I execute `nslookup application.domain.compagny` it displays : can't find XXXXXXXX: SERVFAIL

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean "company" or "compagny" ?

Try these zone configurations:

```
zone "domain.company" {
        type forward;
        forwarders { IP_internaldns; };
};
zone "domain2.company" {
        type forward;
        forwarders { IP_internaldns; };
};
```